# 500 after yii install

Tags: php, apache, yii

I am installing the Yii framework.  I have the following folder structure:

```
sites
|- hr4
|-- yiib
|--- htdocs *this is the web root*
|- yii
|-- framework
```

The requirement checker gave me a pass.  So I enter

```
yiic webapp ../../hr4/yiib/htdocs
```

Everything gets created just fine.  The assets folder is 777'ed and so are the "data" and "runtime" folders within the "protected" folder.

Here is the index.php in htdocs:

```
<?php

// change the following paths if necessary
$yii=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../yii/framework/yii.php';
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/main.php';
// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($yii);
Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
```

and finally my .htaccess file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

When I attempt to acess this site with my browser I get:

## Internal Server Error

I have somewhat limited command line access to this server.  I'm working on getting sudo access, but in the meantime any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: check the logs! Or enable error_reporting

Comment: what line gives you 500? and what about mode of assets folder?

Comment: Thanks guys, After checking the error logs it turns out that index.php was writeable by group.  after 644ing it, it's all good now. If one of you two want to post that as the answer, I'll give you a check-mark.

Comment: It's ok I dont think my comment was worth an answer. I'm still glad it worked out and you learned something (_which is imo the whole purpose of SO, rather then collecting points that is_).